# How to use Session Variable in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have declared Session variable in "Global.asax" file as,

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            int temp=4;
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("_SessionCompany",temp);
        }
```

And want to use this Session Variable into My Controller's action as,

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var test = this.Session["_SessionCompany"];
            return View();
        }
```

But I am Getting Exception While accessing the Session Variable.
Please help me on this that How can I access the Session Variable into my controller's Action.

I am getting an Exception like 
`"Object Reference not set to an Insatance of an object"`
in `Application_Start` in Global.asax  on line

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("_SessionCompany",temp);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker he specified it in ApplicationStart, it doesn't matter what the exception is, his code wont work, no doubt its a NullReferenceException though.

Comment: You should probably use the Session_Start event

Comment: @Phil The error isn't for us; it's for the future users that make this mistake and searching (rightfully so) for "Error text + Session Variable".

Comment: ok @GeorgeStocker - fair point!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The thread that starts the Application is not the request thread used when the user makes a request to the web page.

That means when you set in the `Application_Start`, you're not setting it for any user.

You want to set the session on `Session_Start` event.

**Edit:**

Add a new event to your global.asax.cs file called `Session_Start` and remove the session related stuff from `Application_Start`

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   int temp = 4;
   HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("_SessionCompany",temp);
}
```

This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 4):

You should not set session variables in Application_Start(), as that method is only called once, when the application kicks off in IIS. It is not session based.

In addition, I assume your controller has a Session property? Have you set it correctly?

Use `HttpContext.Current.Session["_SessionCompany"]` rather than `this.Session["_SessionCompany"]` - that should work.

Comment: But I am getting Exception in Application_Start if Global.asax

Comment: Yes, you will get an exception if you try to access HttpContext.Current.Session in the Application_Start() method, as the code is ran in a different thread within IIS - it is executed by the application pool, independently of any users connecting to your website. At this moment, a Session does not exist.

As @Phill has said, you should use the Session_start() method in Global.asax instead.

Comment: The Session property is a property that comes from the Controller abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

In controller, you can access like this..

YourControllerID.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Session["_SessionCompany"]

Answer (score 0):

Use this helper class:

```
namespace Projectname.UI.HtmlHelpers
{
    //[DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public static class SessionHelper
    {
        public static T Get<T>(string index)
        {
            //this try-catch is done to avoid the issue where the report session is timing out and breaking the entire session on a refresh of the report            


            if (HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
            {
                var i = HttpContext.Current.Session.Count - 1;

                while (i >= 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var obj = HttpContext.Current.Session[i];
                        if (obj != null && obj.GetType().ToString() == "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportHierarchy")
                            HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAt(i);
                    }

                    i--;
                }
                if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Equals("~/Home/Default"))
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Home/Default");
                }
                throw new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationException(string.Format("You session has expired or you are currently logged out.", index));
            }

            try
            {
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys.Count > 0 && !HttpContext.Current.Session.Keys.Equals(index))
                {

                    return (T)HttpContext.Current.Session[index];
                }
                else
                {
                    var i = HttpContext.Current.Session.Count - 1;

                    while (i >= 0)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            var obj = HttpContext.Current.Session[i];
                            if (obj != null && obj.GetType().ToString() == "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportHierarchy")
                                HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAt(i);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAt(i);
                        }

                        i--;
                    }
                    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Equals("~/Home/Default"))
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Home/Default");
                    }
                    throw new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationException(string.Format("You session does not contain {0} or has expired or you are currently logged out.", index));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var i = HttpContext.Current.Session.Count - 1;

                while (i >= 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var obj = HttpContext.Current.Session[i];
                        if (obj != null && obj.GetType().ToString() == "Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportHierarchy")
                            HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        HttpContext.Current.Session.RemoveAt(i);
                    }

                    i--;
                }
                if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.Equals("~/Home/Default"))
                {
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Home/Default");
                }
                return default(T);
            }
        }

        public static void Set<T>(string index, T value)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session[index] = (T)value;
        }
    }
}
```

and in your controller you set everything e.g. a login controller:

```
Session Helper.Set<string>("Username", Login User.User Name);
Session Helper.Set<int?>("Tenant Id", Login User.Tenant Id);
SessionHelper.Set<User Type>("User Type");
SessionHelper.Set<string>("", Login User To String());
SessionHelper.Set<int>("Login User Id", Login User.Login UserId);
SessionHelper.Set<string>("Login User", Login User.To String());
SessionHelper.Set<string>("Tenant", Tenant);
SessionHelper.Set<string>("First name", Login User.First Name);
SessionHelper.Set<string>("Surname", Login User.Surname);
SessionHelper.Set<string>("Vendor ", Vendor );
SessionHelper.Set<string>("Wholesaler ", Wholesaler );
SessionHelper.Set<int?>("Vendor Id", Login User );
SessionHelper.Set<int?>("Wholesaler Id", Login User Wholesaler Id);
```

and you just call it anywhere you want:

```
var CreatedBy = SessionHelper.Get<int>("LoginUserId"),
```

it is a simple get to the the entity or set to assign it.

Comment: If this answers the OP's question you should explain how. Just dropping a blob of code down does nothing to help the OP understand their problem, or your solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
public ActionResult DeclareSession()
{ 
    int id=3;
    Session["User"]=id;
    int iUserID =Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["User"].toString());
    return true;
}
```

Comment: using the old Session variable way on mvc will sometimes freak out  and then you have to create a cookiesession manager.