# Have a form result invisible until submission?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, forms

I have a simple web application where the user inputs three integers into a form and receives the sum as a result.

My question is this: I'd like to have the actual sum value not appear until the user has Submitted. Meaning, when the page is opened up, the ViewBag just displays nothing. And then after submission, the ViewBag content appears. Is it possible for me to do this with the current code I have?

I'm aware this will probably require a JavaScript function. I just don't have very much experience integrating JS with C#.

View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<form action="" method="post">

Enter the 1st Number: <input id="firstInt" name="firstInt" type="text" value="0" /><br />
Enter the 2nd Number: <input id="secondInt" name="secondInt" type="text" value="0" /><br />
Enter the 3rd Number: <input id="thirdInt" name="thirdInt" type="text" value="0" /><br />

<input id="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
<input id="Reset" type="reset" value="reset" /><br /><br />
Sum = @ViewBag.result
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(int firstInt = 0, int secondInt = 0, int thirdInt = 0)
    {
        int sum = firstInt + secondInt + thirdInt;
        ViewBag.result = sum;
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use AJAX from JS to call the controller & set sum result on any element. If you're doing POST, make sure that `action` attribute in form triggers call to existing action method name.

Comment: I wouldn't use JS to hide and show in this case. You can modify your C# view code to only show that line in response to a POST, or only show that line when `@ViewBag.result` is defined. If you were going to use JS then you'd use JS to do the whole calculation rather than submitting a form to the web server and getting a response back.

Comment: how about `<input type="hidden" name="sum" id="sum">`? with jQuery you can update `$('#sum').val(...)` value in realtime while it's not being visible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Possible, if you create session variable instead of viewBag.
You better to refer this link [How to  use session variable in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350327/how-to-use-session-variable-in-mvc)

Best practice use ajax when possible